# jquery select dynamically added images on error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam using js/jQuery to add images to my site like this:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.width = imgWidth;
img.file = fileList[i];
img.name = 'pic_' + i;
img.classList.add("obj");
```

But sometimes the url is broken because the image does not exist.
In this case I would like to hide the broken image.
The Problem is that Iam not able to catch the onerror event... if there is any.
All I see is the broken image with this code:

```
<img width="200" src="php/upload.php?action=showPic&amp;newsId=239">
```

I tried a couple of things:

```
$("img").error(function () {
    alert("error");
});
```

or with live:

```
$("img").live('load',(function() { console.log("image loaded correctly"); }));
$("img").live('error',(function() { console.log("image error"); }));
```

But no events are getting triggered :-/

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try setting the error handler before setting the image's source?

Comment: [s] Where did you put `$("img").[...]` ? Try `$(function() { /*put it here*/ }`. This will execute when the document's 'ready' state is fired. See http://api.jquery.com/ready/.. [/s] edit: Ah wait, it's dynamically added so $("img") won't select it until it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create the image with jQuery, you can use the error() function:

```
$('<img />', {width  : imgWidth, 
              src    : fileList[i], 
              name   : 'pic_' + i, 
              'class': 'obj'
}).error(function() {
    $(this).hide();
}).appendTo('somewhere');
```

If it's a native JS element, the onerror function would be the way to go:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.width = imgWidth;
    img.name = 'pic_' + i;
    img.classList.add("obj");
    img.onerror = function() {
        this.style.display = 'none';
    }
    img.src = fileList[i];
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DamkP/)

Not sure what `img.file` is for, but I'm assuming it's the src attribute you're trying to set, and also `classList.add()` does'nt have the best browser support, and seems like a strange way to add a class to a newly created element, when `img.className = 'obj'` is available?

Comment: I tried your first solution with jQuery but the onerror event doesn't seem to get fired :-/ Maybe I need some other method to check if the image is loaded...

Comment: If you try the fiddle, the first image should be hidden, and you'd check that by opening the console and seeing that it has the display set to none, and this works for me. jQuery does'nt have an onerror event, that's a native JS event, and note that onload and onerror should be set before the source is set etc. How do you know the error event is'nt fired, how do you use this, is it inside a document.ready function etc?

Comment: @adeneo: Thanks, didn't know about .error(). The Fiddle looks good.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating your image DOM node you should attach an onerror event

```
...
img.name = 'pic_' + i;
img.onerror = hidebroken;
...

var hidebroken = function(){
    this.setAttribute('style', 'display:none !important');
}
```